# Type Aliases from TypeScript in Dart

Tags: typescript, types, dart

Its possible to use type from TypeScript in Dart?

Sample (TypeScript):

```
export type Speed = 'very slow' | 'slow' | 'normal' | 'fast' | 'very fast';

public getRealSpeed(speed: Speed): number {
    switch(speed) {
       ...
    }

    return 0;
}
```

or

```
public getRealSpeed(speed: 'slow' | 'fast' | 'unknown'): number {
    switch(speed) {
       //TODO
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Dart enum for the same behavior:

```
enum Speed { verySlow, slow, normal, fast, veryFast; }
int getRealSpeed(Speed speed) {
  switch (speed) {
    case Speed.verySlow: return 1;
    ...
    case Speed.veryFast: return 99;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

This does mean that you have to convert strings values to `Speed` instances explicitly, perhaps using

```
const speedByName = {
  "very slow": Speed.verySlow,
  "slow": Speed.slow,
  "normal": Speed.normal,
  "fast": Speed.fast,
  "very fast": Speed.veryFast,
};
```